# cannot navigate to the target tag in DOM by using numbers in bracket, like div[4]

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using *Java* and *Selenium* to write a test. I have this at DOM:

```
...
<div class='a'>
    <div class='b'>
         <div class='1'></div>
         <div class='2'></div>
    </div>
/div>
...
```

I am using this Xpath:

```
//div[@class='a']//div[2]
```

to get to `<div class='1'></div>`

but I am taken to:

`<div class='2'></div>`

in simple words please explain why and how to handle this situation. I do know I can use the `class` attribute to get to an element like :

`//div[@class='1']`

but I want to use numbers in bracket style like `div[and-a-number-here]`

Is there any way to get all divs under a tag and the select the one by the number?

Answer (score 1):

In your xpath:

```
//div[@class='a']//div[2]
```

you are searching for any div which is second descendant of the div with a class=a. That's why it's returning you the 2nd div with class=2.

To get the desired element use xpath like this:

```
//div[@class='a']/div/div[1]
```

Comment: This will return two divs - div class b and div class 1... for getting div with class 1. you try this - //div[@class='a']/div/div[1]

Comment: sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: is there any way to get all div under a tag and the select the one by the number